# Does CORS allow for the use of the "Prefer" header?

Tags: ajax, tomcat, cors, odata

I'm working on an Ajax application that pulls data from a oData Rest service.

The oData service needs me to send an additional header:

```
Prefer : odata.maxpagesize = 20
```

I've updated my Cors filter to allow it like so, (by the way this is running off a Tomcat server).

```
     <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Perfer,odata-maxversion,content-type,cache-control,postman-token,authorization,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

But it's not working and I keep getting the dreaded:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/pfs/odata/BEER/?.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

All other calls work perfectly and if don't pass the additional "Perfer" header it works as well.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turns out I just had a typo in the Cors filter.